# Different Versions of an App per Region

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect

We are currently building apps to be deployed to multiple regions, all would be built from a single code base with the appropriate localisation tailoring it for each locale.

When we introduce new features or fix defects we might want to phase the roll out of the new version of the app rather than introducing it in every region all at once.

My question is how much support does iTunes Connect and Google Play have for us to have different versions of the same app deployed in different regions?

Comment: You localize for one app and all regions get the update, even if nothing changes for them. If you *really* need a different version for different regions, then you'll need to upload them as different apps (thus with different app identifiers, etc.)

Comment: Isn't it a problem to upload different Apps with different same name?